# How to use if let with another statement in swift?

Tags: string, if-statement, swift

If want to both assign a string and check that its not empty in Swift.

```
if let alternative3Text = attributes.stringForKey("choiceThree") && alternative3Text != "" {
   // do stuff with alternative3Text
}
```

Is this possible in Swift, or do i have to do a nested if-statement?

Comment: No, it's not possible, alternative3Text is only visible inside if body {}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** As of Swift 3 (Xcode 8), additional clauses are 
separated by a *comma,* not by `where`:

```
if let alternative3Text = attributes.string(forKey: "choiceThree"),
        alternative3Text != "" {
    // do stuff with alternative3Text
}
```

**Update:** As of Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta), you *can* combine 
optional binding with additional conditions:

```
if let alternative3Text = attributes.stringForKey("choiceThree") where alternative3Text != "" {
   // do stuff with alternative3Text
}
```

Using switch-case still works but is not necessary anymore for this purpose.

---

**Old answer:**
It is not possible with an `if` statement, but with `switch`.
A switch case can use a `where` clause to check for additional conditions
([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)).

Assuming (from your question) that `attributes.stringForKey("choiceThree")` returns
`String?`, the following would work:

```
switch (attributes.stringForKey("choiceThree")) {
case .Some(let alternative3Text) where alternative3Text != "":
    // alternative3Text is the unwrapped String here
default:
    break
}
```

Comment: cool, didn't know about the switch where clause -- ... but that would he would have a if let AND a switch so the sample doesn't help him AFAIK!?

Comment: @Daij-Djan: I am not sure if I understand your question. The `case .Some(let alternative3Text)` does the optional binding (via pattern matching), this *replaces* the `if let`.

Comment: This is a really handy use of pattern matching in general, but it's worth noting that, for a single case, simply nesting an `if` inside an `if let` might be more concise. (Of course, concise is in the eye of the beholder.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't require additional expressions to be true in an if let statement. You will need to add additional code to do this in either the form of a nested if statement as you've already mentioned, or in some other way. If your only requirement is to keep this statement looking clean and wouldn't mind moving some of the logic elsewhere, you could always make an extension to what ever type your attributes variable is to add this functionality.

Here's an example if attributes was an instance of NSUserDefaults. (just because it already contains a stringForKey() instance method.)

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    func nonEmptyStringForKey(key: String) -> String? {
        let full = self.stringForKey(key)

        return full != "" ? full : nil
    }
}
```

And then use it like this

```
if let alternative3Text = attributes.nonEmptyStringForKey("choiceThree") {
    // stuff
}
```